# Js Interval With Random Text and Img

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want my script to not repeat with previous result and always show an image and a text that must match with each other.

When the function calls the same array than previously, all images style are display:blocked.
thank you

```js
setInterval(function (){

var titles = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"];

var whattitle = Math.floor(Math.random()*((titles.length)));

setTimeout(function(){$(".imagespops")[whattitle].style.display="none";}, 1000);            

document.getElementById('textoo').innerHTML = titles[whattitle];  

document.getElementsByClassName('imagespops')[whattitle].style.display="block";


      
}, 1000);
```

```css
.imagespops {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container">
     <img class="imagespops" src='http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=1'>
     <img class="imagespops" src='http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=2'>
     <img class="imagespops" src='http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=3'>
     <img class="imagespops" src='http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=4'>
</div>
   <div class="text-container">
     <div id="textoo"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. What exactly is the problem you are having when you try to do this? Telling us what you want is not enough - please edit your question to tell us what you have already done yourself to do this and what the problems were that you ran into, wh we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to say when the random function yields the same number, every images has `display:none` so there's no image. You're using nested timer and it is the problem. When the random function yields the same index with the previous one, nested timer from previous call(which changes `display` to `none`) overwrites its display attribute.
If you just want to show the image and title which matchs with the index, just clear all images before show a new image. I used jQuery since you included in your html.

```js
setInterval(function (){
var titles = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"];
var whattitle = Math.floor(Math.random()*((titles.length)));

$(".imagespops").css("display", "none");
$(".imagespops."+titles[whattitle]).css("display", "block");
$("#textoo").html(titles[whattitle]);      
}, 1000);
```

```css
.imagespops {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container">
     <img class="imagespops text1" src='http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=1'>
     <img class="imagespops text2" src='http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=2'>
     <img class="imagespops text3" src='http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=3'>
     <img class="imagespops text4" src='http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=4'>
</div>
   <div class="text-container">
     <div id="textoo"></div>
```

P.S. see @FluffyKitten's comment and remember it when you ask your next question.